# ASP.NET MVC application hosted in Azure VM IIS with https, ajax call not working

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, https, asp.net-ajax

I have an ASP.NET MVC application which works perfectly on localhost, and I'm using AD authentication with HTTPS.

When I hosted the app in an Azure VM, everything works perfectly except for the Ajax call. The Ajax call is used to render a partial view content.

jQuery (POD.js) Ajax Call :

```
$(document).ready(function () {
function ShowData(xMaterial, xDescription, xPGIDate, xAll, xPod, xLot) {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: "/POD/Index",
        data: { Material: xMaterial, Description: xDescription, PGIDate: xPGIDate, All: xAll, cbPod: xPod, cbLot: xLot },
        dataType: "html",
        success: function (evt) {
            $('#PODList').html("");       
            $('#PODList').html(evt);
        },
        error: function (err) {
            alert(err.statusText);
        }
    });
}
}
```

Controller :

```
 [HttpPost]
 public PartialViewResult Index(string Material = "", string Description = "", DateTime? PGIDate = null, bool All = true, bool cbPod = false, bool cbLot = false)
    {
        try
        {
            List<POD> Model = new List<POD>();

            //Some code

            return PartialView("_Index", Model);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        { 
            throw ex;
        }

    }
```

HTML view part:

```
<div id="PODList"></div>

<script src="~/Scripts/customScript/POD.js"></script>
```

jQuery Ajax call returns "Not Found" error. Why is this happening only on VM is it something to do with HTTPS? Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because the url for the action method can vary depending where it is deployed on the server. The recommended approach is always to use `Url.Action` helper for generating urls like below:

```
<div id="PODList" data-url="@Url.Action("Index","POD")"></div>
```

and similarly for assets and resources like js, css files and images we should use `Url.Content` :

```
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/customScript/POD.js")"></script>
```

and then need to use the data-url in the ajax call for `url`:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: $('#PODList').data("url"),
    ......
    ......
});
```

Comment: Yeah that was the issue. Thank you so much